# Strengthening micro USB connector

Tags: usb, glue

The connector blows its solder when inserting the cable. It is SMD type.
Can I back it up with a special glue? What do you recommend?
[image]

I saw red little balls on a Xilinx board are these glue?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to repair that board or prevent damage in future on different boards? Because it looks like you have damaged the pads. It will be a bit difficult to repair, I think. That type of connector is not strong enough by itself. In products it usually is supported by the plastic housing or case. For a bare PCB, it is very fragile. You could try putting epoxy encapsulation material on it, but then rework will be totally impossible.

Comment: From the photo it looks like the entire copper pad was delaminated from the PCB... if this connector does not have through-hole shield pins, then its strength depends entirely on the shear strength of the PCB copper layer. Using either a larger copper area for shield connection, or using thicker copper foil, should help. The connector on the Xilinx board looks like it may have through-hole shield tabs, which would help provide more mechanical strength.

Comment: Thick epoxy potting compound. Something that cures and becomes fairly rigid. I don't think silicone will help much because it allows some movement.

Comment: @mkeith I'm not trying repairing this one. For future i'm trying to increase the strength of the connector. But i don't have a chance to change connector or PCB now :( What properties should epoxy have? Do you recommend a special one?

Comment: I would try one that is thick and/or thixotropic. Something sold as an encapsulation epoxy or encapsulation/potting. I don't know where you are or what is available to you. But use an epoxy formulated for use on PCB's. Just to make sure it does not have any conductive or corrosive additives. You will have to experiment and verify with testing.

Comment: Lastly where to apply epoxy? To metal or plastic part to the connector? or both.

Comment: You want to create a mechanical bridge between the main body of the connector and the PCB. So it should form a large "blob" that touches the PCB and connector behind and if possible also on the sides of the connector. Just make sure it doesn't get on the contacts inside the connector.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would do on future boards, is to add 3-4 vias around each of the ground pads of the connector, connected to the pads wia a plane. Then make sure to have a plane area on the bottom of the board as well connecting the vias together.

These extra vias act as an anchor which ties the ground pads through the board giving them significantly higher strength. Place two on the inside of the pads, and two on the outside of the pads.

Secondly, during assembly you could instruct your assembly house to bond the connector to the board with Epoxy (e.g. the red dots you see in the second image). They should already be set up for this as they deal with double-sided circuit boards and tall surface mount components like capacitors.

As a third option, you could use a different USB connector. Some have little plastic pegs underneath them which act as alignment pegs but also provide some strength to resist the connector being pushed backwards. Alternatively a mixed-technology connector which are surface mount style but have through-hole ground pins for added strength.